# javafx2: Data change place in tableview and can't validate change when they was edited

Tags: javafx-2, tableview, tablerow, tablecell

I have a problem with a TableView and custom Row.
I explain the problem:

I have a TableView with exactly 84 items. So I bind my ObservableList to the TableView and create custom row.
I have a custom row with two buttons and one with a TextLabel and a ComboBox.
I can edit the row with the TextLabel through the combobox.
When i have edited my row, the button validates the changes for another cell on the same line and the button goes to disable(false). So i can click on them.

But when i scroll down or up on my TableView the line change and my modification are not at the same object. That is my problem.

Here is a zip of my test project [project link](https://mega.co.nz/#!3ZlXnADD!CBfGJ022kv3dOW6NvypMvxBK1Vt_JyVd0P9GYqnqb-o)

Thanks for your help.

Sylvain

Comment: Please, present your code here, don't provide external links.

Comment: If I am getting your question. You can refer this link: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111803/how-to-do-per-keystroke-validation-of-textfieldtablecell)